# ¿Como abrir puerto COM Arduino de mi pc con app en heroku?

Tags: nodejs, arduino, heroku, serialport

Estoy realizando una aplicación web, uso Nodejs en WIndows 10, todo funciona localmente perfecto, pero cuando subo mi app a Heroku, me da este error al momento de abrir el puerto serial de Arduino:

```
2020-02-25T19:06:15.325036+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error: No such file or directory, cannot open COM8
2020-02-25T19:06:15.325136+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
2020-02-25T19:06:15.325252+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

mi codigo en el servidor Nodejs

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');
var session = require('express-session');
var app = express();

var serialPort = require("serialport");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;  
var server = app.listen(PORT, () => { 

})
var serialPort = require("serialport");
```

var readData;

```
   serial = new serialPort(COM8,{parser: new serialPort.parsers.Readline("\r\n"),"baudRate": 9600});    

      serial.on('open',function(err){

      if(err != null)

      else{   serial.on('data', function (data) {
              readData += data.toString();
              console.log("dato serial" + readData);
               }
             });

      });
```

Comment: No existe una manera sencilla de hacer lo que deseas. Los puertos COM son FÍSICOS y por tanto sólo son alcanzables por la máquina física que los tiene. Si quieres comunicar una app en Heroku con tu arduino necesitarías dos 'servidores'. uno corriendo localmente con tu Arduino que le envíe datos a tu segundo servidor instalado en Heroku. Recomiendo usar WebSockets (socket.io u otro) para datos en tiempo real, sino simples http's en intervalos funcionarán también.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, Si entiendo, también me hacía la pregunta de si era posible tal vez con otra librería adicional, por ejemplo también use la plataforma ngrok para publicar mi app en internet y si funciona pero el problema es que el enlace es variable y necesito que sea estático, o tal vez otra plataforma que soporte de alguna forma lo que necesito?